# Do all moderators stand for re-election?

Tags: support, election

I notice we have a new election!

Do all moderators stand for re-election? Or does the election add new moderators to our existing 6?

As a follow up question, three (possibly four) of our moderators are active and do a great job. I haven't seen two of them active in the time I've been here (the larger part of this year). If not all moderators stand for re-election, should we be requesting removal of the inactive moderators at this time too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current moderators stay as they are, we are on the hook until we make decision to retire or are removed (typically for inactivity).

As per election page there are two *new* positions to be filled with newly elected moderators.

Comment: Oops, thanks Rarst - I didn't notice the position number on the election page. What about the currently inactive moderators - should we be doing anything to request removal? While we have 6 moderators at present, we really only have 4, so it would seem to make sense to end up with 6 active mods after this election rather than end up with 8, which seems like a lot.

Comment: Well, if you want to loudly complain about inactive mods you certainly can. :) Usually no one bothers to, just now and then higher powers prune those _very_ absent.

Comment: Ok cool, that answers my question. Happy with the status quo if that is what is usually done. :)

Comment: @TimMalone I'd argue there's no tangible downside to having a few inactive admins on the site. Removing their ability to return to active duty seems like it could only penalize the site.

Comment: @bosco True. It's probably just my OCD wanting to clean up [this page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). ;)

Comment: @TimMalone but if we get two more there'll be a nice and even two rows XD